# POP3 message format rfc

Tags: pop3

I'm currently coding, as the part of a bigger project, a webmail client.

I'd just need a quick reference and/or pointer towards the right direction about POP3 messages, as I'll have to parse them.

I don't want to use available libraries for this. I just need to know if there is something I can read to understand what to expect in a message.

Thanks!

[Precision Edit:] I'm really talking about a single message's syntax, here. There are "From" fields, and "To" fields, and many other fields, like Mime-Type and stuff, and I want to know if there is a doc somewhere that specifies what is sent back on a successful RETR command.

[Addendum] One might want to look up RFC 822 in addition to RFC 1939.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RFC is [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt)

And [here's](http://mike-java.blogspot.com/2008/03/simple-pop3-client-in-java-tutorial.html) a java tutorial on the subject.

Comment: Not quite what I'm searching for, I haven't been clear, sorry. I need to know the "format" of what is returned in a RETR, how is it built, and what can I expect from it.

Comment: Okay, I fail at reading. Thanks for the java part, that's what I needed.